# Angular js initiation moduler

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I am facing a problem in AngularJS 1.2.15 `$injector:modulerr`. It is working fine if i run my app with MAMP Apache server locally but not working with node server i got this below error. See i know if i missed any dependancies this error will throw but in my case i didn't used any of them just one line of code thats it.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]      
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=myapp&p1=Error%3A%…g%2F1.2.15%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dmyapp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(...<omitted>...1)
```

it's really weird.

This is the code that i used.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
```

Can anyone explain what is going on ?

Comment: Please use the non-minified version of angular.js to get a readable error message.

Comment: @tasseKATT i used non-minified version now still getting error. Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myapp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myapp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify

Answer (score 0):

var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute'])

Comment: kindly read my description properly. I mentioned that i am not using any dependancies.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error due to executing the JS-part too late (using TomEE).
Now i'm initialising the app-Module earlier and everything works fine.